# Постоянно всплывающее окно настроек cookies

Tags: дефект, cookie

С недавнего времени, при заходе на сайт (и meta, и ruSO), стало отображаться, ниже представленное, окно выбора настроек cookies. Проблема в том, что при любом выборе настроек, окно отображается снова при обновлении страницы. Антибанер и блокировщик рекламы отключен. Браузер Google Chrome 120.0.6099.217. Windows 10 Pro 22H2 Build 19045.3930. Резидент ЕС.
Только у меня такая проблема?

[image: Окно настроек cookies]

Если развернуть список партнёров:

[image: Список партнёров]

Comment: Странное какое-то окно. На "Русском языке" в приватном режиме у меня [такое](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bhSMN.jpg). На руСО вообще нет. А что там в списке партнёров, если развернуть?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ обновил вопрос...

Comment: Скорее всего, дело в стране. Для разных стран используются разные рекламные фирмы, поэтому и глюки разные.

Comment: А "партнеры" вот откуда растут: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395258/370389

Comment: У меня дома такая же проблема.... А на работе нет этого окна

Comment: @АлексейШиманский дом в ЕС, а работа сбоку? :)

Comment: с компа нет, с телефона да(причем появилось только вчера), предлагаю удалить старые куки (очистить память навигатора) и больше "вроде" не повторяется. Осмелюсь предположить, что с недавно когда то...... ввели какую то новую "политику" и куки конфликтуют...

Comment: а, ну по ссылке выше так и описано, что ввели новшество с 16января. я почистила память и больше "пока" не повторяется (обновила раз тридцать...)

Comment: на домашнем компе такой проблемы нет, на рабочем есть. И появилось ДО 16 января.

Comment: ...только что меня деконнект с сайта, просто...открыта вкладка, и потом окошко войдите  в систему, и теперь после входа это окно с куками/луной на весь экран всплывает...

Comment: ...возможно, возможно...что это совпадение, но все же. После того, как это окошко бесперерывно всплывало, я зашла на метуEn =приняла там куки, потом Enstack =>тоже приняла, и потом тут исчезло...странно конечно, но после того, как я так сделала, больше пока не появлялось и не бесило огромное окно на весь экран...

Comment: @Dev18 сделал по вашему рецепту - принял куки на enSO и ruSO - и назойливое окно перестало донимать. Спасибо!

Comment: @АлексейР странно да, я думаю, если находится в Европе (или ЗА пределами России), то видимо основные куки на EnSo, а второстепенные на RuSo (чего раньше не замечалось да и вообще wtf), получается куки связаны(?зачем), когда я заметила "связь" мне стало не по себе, а что если один день, мы не сможем открыть сайт РуСо ☹️(мои мысли могут показаться тут не связанными, но зачастую я редко ошибаюсь и донести всю цепочку мыслей тут слишком долго...), но думаю/надеюсь мы еще далеки от таких ограниченийи как грится пока нашли решение и работает => наслаждаемся